# Change text value with image based on row value in gridview using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to change row data with images based on it's value. For instance the row value is "seven", it must be changed with an image of an eagle.

I have tried below codes but got an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim myVal As String = e.Row.Cells(10).Text
        If myVal = "1" Then
            Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image1"), Image)
            img.ImageUrl = "~\images\cat.GIF" 
        ElseIf myVal = "7" Then
            Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image2"), Image)
            img.ImageUrl = "~\images\eagle.GIF" 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Below is the Gridview aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    Height="672px" Width="1037px">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And below is the codes for binding csv file to gridview:

```
 Dim csvFileName As String = "DATA.csv"

        'Change this to your csv file path
        Dim pathofcsv As String = strFolder
        Dim conString As String = "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + pathofcsv + ";Extensions=csv"
        ds = New DataSet("MyDataSet")
        Dim adp As New OdbcDataAdapter()
        Using conn As New OdbcConnection(conString)
            Using cmd As New OdbcCommand(Convert.ToString("SELECT * FROM ") & csvFileName, conn)
                conn.Open()
                adp.SelectCommand = cmd
                adp.Fill(ds)
            End Using
        End Using

        grid.DataSource = ds
        grid.DataBind()
        grid.Rows(0).Visible = False


        'Rename Columns Names
        With grid.HeaderRow
            .Cells(0).Text = "ANIMAL NAME"
            .Cells(1).Text = "VALUE NO."
        End With
```

Where "VALUE NO." is the number of image stores in the my.resources.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please also add the `<Columns>` section of `GridView1`

Comment: Sir the Columns of Girdview1 was binded from a csv file.

Comment: Please check my edited answer below, I think I found out the cause.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your last message in the chat room, please have a look at my reply here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14190311#14190311

Answer (score 1):

Looks like these two lines generate the error:

```
Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image1"), Image)
Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image2"), Image)
```

Since the data is from a csv, you need to add `Image1` in the aspx code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
    Height="672px" Width="1037px">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and delete this line:

```
Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image2"), Image)
```

After inserting `Image1` to the `GridView1`, you will need to get `myVal` from the 10th column instead of 9th:

```
Dim myVal As String = e.Row.Cells(11).Text
```

To avoid repetition, you only need to declare `img` once before the `If` block:

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim myVal As String = e.Row.Cells(11).Text
        Dim img As Image = TryCast(e.Row.FindControl("Image1"), Image)
        If myVal = "1" Then
            img.ImageUrl = "~\images\cat.GIF" 
        ElseIf myVal = "7" Then
            img.ImageUrl = "~\images\eagle.GIF" 
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: data from csv file are numbers, every numbers has an equal image but its not included in csv file

Comment: Sir I tried your suggested codes but what happens is that the first column was emptied and no image appear on the gridview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45602/discussion-between-ekad-and-j-j)